# Font Latin Modern Roman cannot be found

Tags: xetex, fontspec, overleaf, docker

I am hosting my Overleaf, and I ran into a wall.
I'm trying to compile my BSc thesis template, but I'm constantly getting error that Latin Modern Roman is missing.
Latin Modern Roman is a part of TeX Live as [read here](https://tug.org/FontCatalogue/latinmodernroman/), so it should just work.

My compiler is set for `XeLaTeX`, as recommended by the authors.
(I cannot share this template here)

I tried installing `scheme-full` but it always finished with couple errors, and it didn't fix anything.

I tried commenting entire statement in question, and it compiled without error. But I'm not sure if it's using the right fonts now.

I have mathspec package installed

```bash
❯ docker exec overleaf tlmgr info mathspec
package:     mathspec
category:    Package
[...]
installed:   Yes
revision:    42773
sizes:       run: 45k
relocatable: No
cat-version: 0.2b
cat-license: lppl
cat-topics:  font-maths font-sel
collection:  collection-latexrecommended
```

these are my schemes

```
i scheme-basic: basic scheme (plain and latex)
  scheme-bookpub: book publishing scheme (core LaTeX and add-ons)
  scheme-context: ConTeXt scheme
  scheme-full: full scheme (everything)
  scheme-gust: GUST TeX Live scheme
i scheme-infraonly: infrastructure-only scheme (no TeX at all)
  scheme-medium: medium scheme (small + more packages and languages)
i scheme-minimal: minimal scheme (plain only)
  scheme-small: small scheme (basic + xetex, metapost, a few languages)
i scheme-tetex: teTeX scheme (more than medium, but nowhere near full)
```

This part creates error

```
\ifXeTeX
    \RequirePackage{mathspec} % wczytuje również fontspec
    \setmainfont{Latin Modern Roman}
    \setromanfont{Latin Modern Roman}
    \setsansfont{Latin Modern Sans}
    \setmonofont{Latin Modern Mono}
    \setmathrm{Latin Modern Math}
    \setmathfont(Digits,Latin)[Scale=MatchLowercase]{Latin Modern Math}
\else
    \RequirePackage{lmodern}
    \renewcommand*\familydefault{\sfdefault}
    \RequirePackage[T1]{fontenc}
\fi
```

[Full logs](https://pastebin.com/uvZUyjQL)(just in case, i'm sorry if I am dropping too much information)

and this is the error in question(redacted for readability)

```
! Package fontspec Error: The font "Latin Modern Roman" cannot be found.

For immediate help type H <return>.
 ...                                              
                                                  
l.104     \setromanfont
                       {Latin Modern Roman}

[...]

Package fontspec Info: Could not resolve font "Latin Modern Roman/BI" (it
(fontspec)             probably doesn't exist).


Package fontspec Info: Could not resolve font "Latin Modern Roman/B" (it
(fontspec)             probably doesn't exist).


Package fontspec Info: Could not resolve font "Latin Modern Roman/I" (it
(fontspec)             probably doesn't exist).
```

I ran minimal document, and [it gave no errors](https://pastebin.com/as7AS4AF)

```
\documentclass{article}\usepackage{fontspec}\begin{document}Hello, world!\end{document}
```

Comment: Welcome! What error did you get when you tried to install the full scheme?

Comment: Try a minimal document e.g. `\documentclass{article}\usepackage{fontspec}\begin{document}Hello, world!\end{document}` and post that code and the log here by editing your question. If LM fonts can't be found, the details of your template etc. aren't relevant: you should easily be able to reproduce the issue with a minimal example. Try the example with LuaLaTeX, too, if that's installed.

Comment: you could simply remove the font settings as latin modern is the default in xelatex, but otherwse use the font file name not the internal font name for xelatex and texlivev supplied fonts

Comment: Also, inspect the working mwe. What fonts did it actually use?

Comment: @cfr I got three errors while installing full scheme, I pasted them here https://pastebin.com/jP23vv4T
I also added minimal config to my post.

Comment: Did removing the font settings work? Or using the file name?